# Javascript global variable doesn't update

Tags: javascript, webgl, unity-ui

Here is the scenario,

I have a GetImageAerial.jslib which has function something like this

```
var GetImageAerial = {
    getImageFromBrowserAerial: function(objectNameAerialPtr, funcNameAerialPtr) {
        var g = window.becauseUnitysBadWithJavacript_getImageFromBrowserAerial || {
            busy: false,
            initialized: false,
            rootDisplayStyle: null,
            root: null,
            ctx: null
        };
        window.becauseUnitysBadWithJavacript_getImageFromBrowserAerial = g;

        if (g.busy) {
            return;
        }
        g.busy = true;

        var objectNameAerial = UTF8ToString(objectNameAerialPtr);
        var funcNameAerial = UTF8ToString(funcNameAerialPtr);

        if (!g.initialized) {
            g.initialized = true;
            g.ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
            g.root = document.createElement("div");
            g.root.innerHTML = [
                '<style>',
                '.getimage {',
                '    position: absolute;',
                '    left: 0;',
                '    top: 0;',
                '    width: 100%;',
                '    height: 100%;',
                '    display: flex;',
                '    flex-flow: column;',
                '    justify-content: center;',
                '    align-items: center;',
                '    z-index: 2;',
                '    color: white;',
                '    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);',
                '    font: sans-serif;',
                '    font-size: x-large;',
                '}',
                '.getimage a, .getimage label {',
                '   background-color: #666;',
                '   border-radius: 0.5em;',
                '   border: 1px solid black;',
                '   padding: 0.5em;',
                '   margin: 0.25em;',
                '   outline: none;',
                '   display: inline-block;',
                '}',
                '.getimage input {',
                '    display: none;',
                '}',
                '</style>',
                '<div class="getimage">',
                '    <div>',
                '        <label for="photo">click to choose an image</label>',
                '        <input id="photo" type="file" accept="image/*"/><br/>',
                '        <a>cancel</a>',
                '    </div>',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n');

            document.body.appendChild(g.root);

            var input = g.root.querySelector("input");
            input.onchange = getPic;
            input.onclick = preventOtherClicks;

            var label = g.root.querySelector("label");
            label.onclick = preventOtherClicks;

            var cancel = g.root.querySelector("a");
            cancel.onclick = handleCancel;

            var getImageElement = g.root.querySelector(".getimage");
            getImageElement.onclick = handleCancel;

            g.rootDisplayStyle = g.root.style.display;
        }

        g.root.style.display = g.rootDisplayStyle;

        function preventOtherClicks(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        }

        function getPic(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            var fileInput = evt.target.files;
            if (!fileInput || !fileInput.length) {
                return sendError("no image selected");
            }

            var picURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileInput[0]);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                handleImageLoad(img, sendResult);
            };
            img.onerror = function() {
                sendError("Could not get image");
            };
            img.src = picURL;
        }

        function handleCancel(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            sendError("cancelled");
        }

        function handleImageLoad(img, sendResultCallback) {
            g.ctx.canvas.width = 256;
            g.ctx.canvas.height = 256;
            g.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, g.ctx.canvas.width, g.ctx.canvas.height);
            var dataUrl = g.ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
            g.ctx.canvas.width = 1;
            g.ctx.canvas.height = 1;
            sendResultCallback(dataUrl);
        }

        function sendError(msg) {
            sendResult("error: " + msg);
        }

        function sendResult(result) {
            g.root.style.display = "none";
            g.busy = false;
            SendMessage(objectNameAerial, funcNameAerial, result);
        }
    }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, GetImageAerial);
```

I have a button call that calls this JS function from C# script which is attached to a gameobject.

```
 public void CallImageAerial()
{
    Debug.Log("Call Image Aerial:" + gameObject.name);
    GetImageAerial.GetImageFromUserAsyncAerial(gameObject.name, "ReceiveImageAerial");
    TurnOffAllButtons();
}

string s_dataUrlPrefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
public void ReceiveImageAerial(string dataUrl)
{
    if (dataUrl.StartsWith(s_dataUrlPrefix))
    {
        byte[] pngData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(dataUrl.Substring(s_dataUrlPrefix.Length));

        // Create a new Texture (or use some old one?)
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1); // does the size matter?
        if (tex.LoadImage(pngData))
        {
            //Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            aerialRenderer.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            aerialRenderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
            Debug.Log("Calling Receive Aerial");
            DoneAerial();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("could not decode image");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error getting image:" + dataUrl);
    }
}
```

I have a class which has reference to the static extern void and imports the DLL

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class GetImageAerial
{

#if UNITY_WEBGL

   [DllImport("__Internal")]
   private static extern void getImageFromBrowserAerial(string objectName, string callbackFuncName);

#endif

   static public void GetImageFromUserAsyncAerial(string objectName, string callbackFuncName)
   {
#if UNITY_WEBGL
       Debug.Log("Inside Get Image " + callbackFuncName);
       getImageFromBrowserAerial(objectName, callbackFuncName);

#else

           Debug.LogError("Not implemented in this platform");

#endif
   }
}
```

The problem I have here is that I do call this JS function multiple times and what I want to do is update the objectNameAerial and funcNameAerial in consecutive calls but that doesn't happen. Javascript always preserves the first value of the variable that was set. I was thinking of setting local variables, but I can't technically do that. Any suggestions are welcome! Been stuck at this for too long!

Thank you!